# Pulling page in jQuery when only fragment is needed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a function for liking posts in a forum. When called, the function works but reloads the page into the div, resulting in a mess. When the likeit button is clicked, the database pulls a count and this function is called to reload the div. I'm trying to load only the div from the function without the extra HTML; how do I manage this?

I attempted to change the load function to a different php page with only the function related code inside, but this gives me a 500 error. If that should work, it's most likely that I'm not pulling the right code into the separate file.

```
function like_post(id)
    {
        $("#like" + id).load("forums.php?t=" . $topic['id'] . "&like=" + id, function() {
            $("#likelink" + id).empty();
            $(function(){$(".smallrollover").tipTip({delay:10});});
        });
    }
```

The load function is pulling all of the HTML from the forums.php page into the like div rather than only the relevant content.

Comment: AJAX will retrieve the entire response, but `load()` offers a filter option, allowing you to select a portion of the page you wish to display.

Comment: Do you use any template system? Or have a base layout? Because if you do these, you need to change base layout to something empty that returns only the html portion you want.

Comment: Hi Marco, I do have a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly with regard to syntax, note that `.` is the PHP concatenation operator, and you don't need the document.ready handler around the `tipTip()` call.

With regard to `load()`, the method accepts a selector used to filter the response HTML so that only the elements you target will be appended to the target:

```
function like_post(id) {
  $("#like" + id).load(`forums.php?t=${$topic['id']}&like=${id} #like${id}`, function() {
    $("#likelink" + id).empty();
    $(".smallrollover").tipTip({ delay: 10 });
  });
}
```

That being said, this isn't a great idea as you're still loading the *entire* page again and then pulling out the relevant parts when all the HTML has been received. It would make more sense to create a separate endpoint which returns only the required HTML, or even JSON which you then build the required HTML structure from on the clientside.

I would also suggest you look in to using common classes as working with dynamic ids in the manner you are generates some unnecessarily ugly code.

Comment: Hi Rory, the script was in a PHP echo, hence the concatenation. The function you suggest isn't working for me. Could you point me in the direction of the other options so I can read up on them?

Comment: There's no real resource to point you to. In this case you would simply need to create a new php file which only returns the data required to be displayed within the `#like` element